# Smaller vertical space between repeated environments

Tags: spacing, environments, conditionals

I have a new environment that is defined with `addvspace` at the beginning and end. This works fine if it is surrounded by text. Now, I want this space to be smaller (`smallskipamount`) between these environments if they follow one another directly. In other words I want the space to be smaller between the environments than it is between the environments and the text. How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{env}
    {\addvspace{\bigskipamount}\bfseries}
    {\par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{env}
Bla bla bla.
\end{env}

\blindtext

\begin{env}
Bla bla bla.
\end{env}

\begin{env}
Bla bla bla.
\end{env}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the "message" in the main vertical list about the end of previous environment using very specific value of penalty. And you can read this value at the start of your environment.

```
\newenvironment{env}
    {\ifnum\lastpenalty=12345 \vskip-\bigskipamount \penalty0 \fi
     \addvspace{\bigskipamount}\bfseries}
    {\par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}\penalty12345 }
```

The `\penalty0` is inserted before `\addvspace` in order to `\addvspace` works in the case of vskip correction.